# Implement Reminder Functionality For Events in Python Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-calendar-api, reminders

I have implemented an event module in our Django application using [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar), and I have set the reminder time on events, now I have to want to get the reminder notification before starting the event in my application, But the delivery mechanisms only available by Google API are

> Pop-up. These are supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.
>
> Email sent by the server.

And they have not provided any of these types of functionality that I can get reminders from Google Calendar to our application. I have tried from [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) of Google Calendar API but it has different functionality.

**Solution:** I have another option to achieve this using [celery beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) and can write **cron job** but it may costly to check from the database after the specific time interval that, is there time matched with event reminder then push the notification. If the events data is on large scale it was a hectic job.

I'm looking for the best solution or any third party tool which is providing the reminder functionality.

Answer (score 1):

*There is currently an open Feature Request on Google Issue Tracker to add an API for reminders for Calendar.*

What you can do in this situation is to star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) and eventually add a comment stating your need for this functionality.

#### Workaround

You can make use of Apps Script's time-driven triggers and trigger the execution of your Python script.

In this situation, you will have to gather the events in Apps Script and check for their start times. If the start time is less than the start time of the event, you will trigger the execution of the Python script. As far as the execution of the Python Script goes, you can host it on a private server or on the cloud and trigger its execution.

#### Code

```
function getEvents() {
    let today = new Date();
    let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    let events = calendar.getEventsForDay(today);
    let startTime = today.getHours();
    let params = {
        'method': 'post',
        'headers': {
           'contentType': 'application/json',
        },
        'payload':'payload'

    };
    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[0].getStartTime() <= startTime) {
            UrlFetchApp.fetch('python_script_url', params);
        }
    }
}
```

As for making sure the `getEvents` function gets executed, you can add an installable time-driven trigger which can run every 10 minutes for example to trigger the execution of the above function.

```
function createTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('getEvents')
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(10)
        .create();
}
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app);
- [GCP HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http).